# Как отключить ненужное сообщение в Vite?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vite

Я вывожу в консоль props функционального компонента React. Я использовал компонент в App.jsx только 1 раз. Vite мне выводит 2 консоль лога:

1. Object {name: "Игорь"}_______________________________________Cart.jsx
2. Object {name: "Игорь"}_______________________________________localhost:5173:342:29

Мне нужно настроить Vite так, чтобы он выводил только первое сообщение в консоль. Как это сделать?